# null:org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I see the following log messages on Solr Admin UI in the Logging section.
Any suggestions on the root cause and how to fix such issues?
The collection runs on SolrCloud(Solr version 4.10) with 2 shards.

```
2/12/2016, 3:27:40 PM
ERROR
SolrDispatchFilter
null:org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Blocklist for /tmp/user1/solr/collection1/data/index/_a_Lucene41_0.tim has changed!
null:org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Blocklist for /tmp/user1/solr/collection1/data/index/_a_Lucene41_0.tim has changed!
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:621)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:229)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

### I can see that ur collection final index dir is **/tmp/user1/solr/collection1/data/index**, i hope this is a test collection, if you wanna get out of this issue just delete (stop the solr instance and trash in ur machine) complete index dir OR move ur index dir to some backup dir and restart should work.

The actual problem could be ur .tim (terms info file) file in index may have been corrupted for some reasons, you may find the reason if you recollect what you have done before u have seen this error.
There are may open source distribution to fix corrupted indexes, you can find if you search.

Hope this helps to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes it is a test collection however I don't wish to come across such issues during production therefore wanted to know the root cause. As far as I can recollect the steps that I did prior to seeing this error were mostly related to Hue where i was accessing the index. Also deleting the index dir would result in loss of all the indexed documents which we would not like to happen in production. So I think trying to fix corrupted indexes would be ideal solution.